# Injecting HttpClient

Tags: c#, cookies, dependency-injection, httpclient, session-cookies

Im currently writing a library that interfaces with a web API and so must make a lot of web requests. For this Im using the HttpClient class.

There is a main "Client" class, which offers methods to make the various valid GET requests to the API. The web API also offers login functionality, and once logged on you can make POST requests.

Id like for there to be a simple check whether you are currently logged in. If I create the HttpClient within my Client class, this is simple:

```cs
public class Client
{
    public bool IsLoggedIn 
    {
        get
        {
            // Check if there is a session cookie
            _httpHandler.
                CookieContainer.
                GetCookies("BaseUri").
                SingleOrDefault(cookie => cookie.Name == "session") != null;
        }
    }
 

    public Client()
    {
        _httpHandler = new HttpHandler();
        _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
    }

    public async void Login() { ... }
    public async void Logout() { ... }
    ...

    private HttpHandler _httpHandler;
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
}
```

However, as far as I know, it's ideal to reuse a HttpClient instance as much as possible.
Therefore Id prefer to inject the HttpClient, so client code has full control over how many HttpClients are instantiated:

```cs
public class Client
{
    public Client(HttpClient client)
    {
        _httpClient = client;
    }

    ...
}
```

When doing it like this, Im not aware of any way to get cookies from the client.

Basically I have two questions:

- Is it better practice to let client code inject the HttpClient?
- If yes, is there any way to get cookies from the injected HttpClient?

Comment: you could take a look at the IHttpClientFactory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Ive looked into it but I dont know if it would be a good fit - in the docs it advises to avoid IHttpClientFactory if you require cookies (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cookies)